# Multiple submission at exact same time in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a form using Google App Script and send all the data in Google Spreadsheet.

My GS CODE:

```
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Form1");
}
```

my html code just a simple input tag and whenever users submit it it will append row in Google Spreadsheet.

Here is my code:

```
function executeProgram(agentSub){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Submission");

  var timeStamp = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow([timeStamp,name,age]);
}
```

Now the code working fine if there are only one people submit the form. But if 2 people submit it at the exact same time, it will only create 1 row instead of 2. Look like the second is overlapped with the first one. But if the second person submitted 1 second after the first person, the code running fine(created 2 row). What am I missing here, and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the lock service

Comment: @Cooper Thanks man! I never heard about it, but when I look at it, that is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

[Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) allows scripts to prevents concurrent access to sections of code. This can be useful when you have multiple users or processes modifying a shared resource and want to prevent collisions.

Lock Service has three different methods depending on the restrictions, in this case you need to use [getScriptLock()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getScriptLock()) to make sure that the code section cannot be executed simultaneously regardless of the identity of the user.

### Step by step

- Define your `Lock` with the previous method `var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();`
- Define the start of your `Lock`, there are two different options:

  - [tryLock(timeoutInMillis)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#tryLock(Integer)) returns false if the lock was not acquired, true otherwise.
  - [waitLock(timeoutInMillis)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitLock(Integer)) throws an exception if the lock could not be acquired
- Define the end of your `Lock` with [releaseLock()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#releaseLock()). It allows other processes waiting on the lock to continue.
- (optional check): [hasLock()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#hasLock()) returns false if

  - lock was not acquired
  - `tryLock` or `waitLock` were never called
  - timed out before the lock could be retrieved
  - `releaseLock()` was called