# One can use the Google Sheets functions async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have the problem that many people access a table (Google Sheet), so it can happen that two people at the same time change a value. Is there a possibility to program the event **async**?

An optional possibility would also be that the table is locked for other participants if the script is not completely executed.

```
function onEdit(e){ 

}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about the answer you expect, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple submission at exact same time in Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65420165/multiple-submission-at-exact-same-time-in-google-app-script)

Answer (score 2):

For example, how about the following 2 sample situations for explaining about the work of OnEdit simple trigger?

#### Sample situation 1:

`onEdit` has the work for 5 seconds. The sample script is as follows.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  e.source.appendRow([new Date()]);
}
```

- When 2 users are edited cells simlutaneously, the average difference of these 2 timestamps is about 1 second. From this result, it is considered that the function of `onEdit` is run with the asynchronous process.

#### Sample situation 2:

`onEdit` has the work for 5 seconds. The sample script is as follows. In this sample, LockService is used.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    try {
      Utilities.sleep(5000);
      e.source.appendRow([new Date()]);
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}
```

- When 2 users are edited cells simlutaneously, the average difference of 2 timestamps is about 5 seconds. From this result, by using the LockService, it is considered that the function of `onEdit` is run with the synchronous process.

#### Note:

- As other report for the event triggers, there is a report about "Asynchronous Processing using Event Triggers". [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5)

#### References:

- [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)